# Linq c# sum any objects from list > int

Tags: c#, linq

I want do *Linq* like in topic.
I have `List<double>` i want to check there is `2` *different* `double` which `sum` is more then for example `20`.
i don't have idea how to do that.
I create something like this

```
tags.Any(x => (x.Distance + tags.Select(y => y.Distance).First() > 20));
```

But it check only with *first* object, and check with myself. 
If `2` elements on list are the same they can be check, but with myself can't.

Can i do something like take this and next object from list?

```
var tags = new List<double>() {
  5, 7, 9, 13 
};

if ((i != j) && (tags(i) + tags(j)) > 20)
{

}
```

This link should work like this `if` when it would be array in a *loop*.

Comment: What is `tags`? Can you show the data-structure and some sample-data as well as expected behaviour?

Comment: Could you provide an *example*? (Both initial data and desired outcome)

Comment: tags are List<double>. I can 1 second

Comment: I think you want `tags.SelectMany(t1 => tags.Where(t2 => t2 != t1).Select(t2 => t1.Distance + t2.Distance)).Any(d => d > 20)`

Comment: iIs t check the element with myself?

Comment: @404 That not going to compile since the result of a `Select` is an `IEnumerable`, but `Any` requires a predicate that returns a `bool`.

Comment: @mdlejtecole `double` doesn't have a `Distance` property. You haven't explained what you want to do either, the title is unclear and the code won't compile. Explain what you want to do, not how you think the solution will look like. `I want to find all tag pairs with a sum greater than 20` is a valid question.

Comment: So you just want to select those two numbers whose sum is greater 20? What if there are multiple pairs? E.g. if tags also contained 12.

Comment: yes i had more variables and i forgot to remove distance, because i wanted to simplify. Thanks for all the answers. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try *Cartesian Join* (`tags` with *itself*):

```
var tags = new List<double>() {
  5, 7, 9, 13
};

var result =  tags
  .Select((a, index_a) => tags
     .Where((b, index_b) => index_a != index_b && a + b > 20)
     .Select(b => Tuple.Create(a, b)))
  .SelectMany(item => item);

// Let's have a look:
Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

**Outcome:**

```
(9, 13)
(13, 9)
```

if you don't want `(13, 9)` and alike pairs (where `index_a > index_b`)

```
var result = tags
  .Select((a, index_a) => tags
    .Skip(index_a + 1)
    .Where(b => a + b > 20)
    .Select(b => Tuple.Create(a, b)))
 .SelectMany(item => item);

// Let's have a look:
Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

**Outcome:**

```
(9, 13)
```

Answer (score 0):

Linq is a fancy cover for for loops, foreach loops and conditional statements, as result I would construct the above question in terms of for loops and conditionals etc, then afterwards look to convert this into a Linq statement.

e.g

```
private List<Tuple<double, double>> GetElementsWhosSumIsGreaterThanX(List<double> originalList, double x)
    {
        //take the absolute value of the variable to eliminate sign errors
        x= Math.Abs(x);

        List<Tuple<double, double>> returnList = new List<Tuple<double, double>>();

        //only go upto count - 1 as there is no more elements to compare the last element to
        for (int i = 0; i < originalList.Count - 1; i++)
        {//loop over each element in turn
            for (int j = i; j < originalList.Count - i; j++)
            {//compare it to the rest of the list from the ith element on               
                double sum = originalList[i] + originalList[j];

                if (sum> x)
                    returnList.Add( new Tuple<double, double>(originalList[i], originalList[j]));
            }
        }

        return returnList;
    }
```

This can be used like:

```
public void Test()
    {
        List<double> tags = new List<double>() {5, 7, 9, 13, 10.1, 25.6, 32.1};

        List<Tuple<double, double>> results = GetElementsWhosSumIsGreaterThanX(tags, 20);

        for (int i = 0; i < results.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} and {1} have a sum greater than 20", results[i].Item1, results[i].Item2);
    }

    /*output:
    5 and 25.6 have a sum greater than 20
    5 and 32.1 have a sum greater than 20
    7 and 25.6 have a sum greater than 20
    9 and 13 have a sum greater than 20
    13 and 13 have a sum greater than 20
    */
    }
```